# Disable Application.CreateForm with new form

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a function which checks the settings and permissions before the start of the application, and if everything goes through, it selects what version to run and accordingly changes the main form.

```
function SomeControlFunction: Boolean;
var
  lMainForm : TForm;
begin
  if SomePermission then
    Application.CreateForm(TUForm1, lMainForm)
  else
    Application.CreateForm(TUForm2, lMainForm);
end;
```

**Project.dpr**

```
Application.Initialize;
if SomeControlFunction then
  Application.Run;
```

Unfortunately every time I create a new form in the project, it automatically adds to `Project.dpr` and I have to delete it every time. Is there any way to disable this behavior or is the whole process wrong and I should run the application differently?

```
Application.Initialize;
if SomeControlFunction then
  Application.CreateForm(TUNewForm, UNewForm);
Application.Run;
```

Comment: For alternately created forms, I typically migrate application initialization to its own unit, because the project file is "owned" by the IDE. Instead, that project file just calls a single function, and all the rest is done in that other unit. Unfortunately, this also breaks everything so you lose many features, because the IDE no longer recognizes it as a VCL  forms application.

Comment: *it automatically adds to Project.dpr and I have to delete it every time*. Tools->Options->Environment Options->Form Designer->, uncheck *Auto create forms & data modules*. You'll still get the unit added to the uses clause at the top, but it won't generate the Application.CreateForm code. I have in the auto-create list (Project->Options->Forms) my datamodule and main form for every application, which creates only those two CreateForm statements. I then wrap those in code that first loads a splash screen and (with a try..finally) closes it at the end just before Application.Run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a work around to prevent the IDE from changing the dpr-file in that way.

It seems that the Delphi IDE will explicitly look for places where the global variable `Application` from `Vcl.Forms` is used in the dpr-file and accordingly add the `CreateForm` calls.

The standard template code in the dpr-file looks like this:

```
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  <-- new forms will be added here automatically
  Application.Run;
```

If you use an 'alias' variable - lets say `App` - instead, the IDE will not interfere. Replace your existing code in the dpr-file with following:

```
var
  App: TApplication;
begin
  App := Application;
  App.Initialize;
  if SomeControlFunction then
    App.Run;
end.
```

Adding new Forms won't automatically add `CreateForm` calls in your dpr-file now.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any way to disable this behavior?

In the options dialog, select the [Form Designer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Form_Designer_Options) node, and uncheck the *Auto create forms & data modules* option.

The documentation for this option states:

> Toggles whether or not to automatically create forms. When unchecked, forms added to the project after the first one are put into the Available Forms list rather than the Auto Create list. You can change where each form is listed by choosing **Project > Options > [Forms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Forms_(dialog_box))**.

What the documentation does not tell you is that this option is ignored when you add a new form to a project that does not already contain at least one auto-create form. So it's probably not going to be very useful for you.

---

By the way, `SomeControlFunction` does not set the return value.

Comment: That function is just a cut example. Anyway, this settings works only if I have at least one form in `Auto-create forms`, otherwise it ignores it.

Comment: Indeed. Perhaps you should submit a bug report.

Comment: Better late than never. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20957

Comment: FYI, bug report was closed with comment saying "it works as expected/designed"